# Как создать корзину на PHP и обработчик "Оформить заказ"?

Tags: php

Помогите или расскажите, как создается корзина на интернет-магазинах, как используются сессии и куки. Я начинающий веб-программист, но никак не могу разобраться, так как информации в интернете подходящей мало, точнее очень много мусора...

Comment: [Информации куча.][1]
[1]: http://www.webchaynik.ru/PHP/Internet_magazin_Korzina_na_PHP_1 
Это только то что я не копаясь нашел.

Comment: Вот чего бы точно не посоветовал так читать бред написанный по ссылке выше ;)

Comment: Для одарённых объясню смысл сего сообщения не в ссылке а в том что найти инфу по этой теме разплюнуть... ;)))) Поэтому не удобряйтесь натуральными удобрениями.

Comment: Разплюнуть найти мусор (что вы собственно говоря и виртуозно продемонстрировали), о чём писал автор ;)

Comment: Не удобряйтесь натуральными удобрениями. ^^

Comment: Советую посмотреть в сторону Ajax и jQuery. Хотя это не так легко как на простом php, зато научитесь как нормальный магазин написать.

Answer (score 1):

1. Пользователь заходит на сайт, запускается сессия, генерируется её уникальный id;
2. При покупке товара в базу данных передается информация о товаре (id товара, кол-во) и уникальный id сессии.
3. При успешном оформлении заказа должна произойти очистка, т.е. из БД удалены все записи содержащие уникальный id сессии, а потом и сама сессия должна быть уничтожена.

Куки можно использовать для того чтобы на догло сохранить информацию о заказе, при этом возникает и задача очистки базы, этот вариант я бы пока не стал рассматривать, хотя он тоже не сложный.

Почитайте книжку Лора Томпсон и Люк Веллинг: "Программирование на php и MySQL" там есть хорошие примеры реализации магазина.